# AngularJS: How do I stub a function inside a controller which I am unit-testing?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, stubbing

I have a controller which is currently calling a RESTful API when the related view is loaded.  As such, I'm not sure if this problem relates to the way in which I'm testing, or the implementation of the code itself - I'd be happy with any any suggestions that tackle the problem holistically, i.e. help me unit-test code that does what I want :)

Here are some samples to illustrate my point:

The controller:

```
angular.module('app.myModule',[])
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.notTestingThis = function() {
    var thisFails = $scope.do.not.want.to.mock.these.objects.substr(0,10);
  };

  $scope.testingThis = function(myString) {
    $scope.newString = myString;
  };

  $scope.notTestingThis();

});
```

The test (as it stands):

```
describe('MyControllerTest', function() {

  beforeEach(module('app.myModule'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.testingThis()', function() {

    it('sets newString', function() {
      $scope = {
        'notTestingThis': {}
      };
      var myController = $controller('MyController', {$scope: $scope});
    });

  });

});
```

When loading this view, I need to call the *notTestingThis* function somehow, however in my unit-test I want to isolate the *testingThis* function.  The problem is that when I initialize the controller in my test, it will of course call *notTestingThis* and attempt to perform actions on objects that do not exist (and which I do not care about in this test).

Obviously attempting to stub out the function in question as per this example is no use as the $scope will be re-written when initialized.  Is there a way to stub out or mock individual functions in a controller that you are attempting to test, or have I missed the point somewhere?  Some suggestions that a colleague put forward were:

> Enhance the controller to be aware of the unit-test itself, allowing you to adjust program flow based on the injected mock, i.e. something like the following in the controller:

```
if (!$scope.methodA) {
   $scope.methodA = function() {...}
}
```

... or ...

> Change the way the *notTestingThis* function is called, by listening to an initialization event from the $rootScope instead of calling it directly, which would allow me to mock the $rootScope so that it doesn't trigger this event, thus preventing *notTestingThis* from being called

I can't help feeling as though I'm thinking about this the wrong way round.  Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just doubling back on this query in case others come to it.  I looked over both recommendations, implementing both with some differences to my original comments (as I'd misunderstood the recommendations) namely:

**Option 1**

Instead of wrapping each function, wrap the calling code in:

```
if(!testingBoolean) { $scope.notTestingThis(); };
```

With testingBoolean false unless passed in as an (optional) argument to the Controller, allowing the testing code to prevent the calls

**Option 2:**

$broadcast from the $rootScope using a Service function.  Wrap the calling code in a listener on that event then call the function from the controller.  Mocking the $rootScope when performing the tests will prevent the notTestingThis function from triggering.

**The real solution**

These approaches seem to have been a distraction however; though it's not explicitly stated anywhere, it does seem that Controllers shouldn't be calling functions themselves.  The right way to go here appears to be to re-architect the app design so that the directives would call the functions through binds, thus simplifying the unit testing.